# Hibernate Envers: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in audit table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I recently upgraded my Spring Boot version from `v2.2.4.RELEASE` to `v2.2.6.RELEASE`, thereby upgrading the Hibernate and Hibernate Envers version from `5.4.10.Final` to `5.4.12.Final`.

### The exception

When I start the application now, I get an exception from the schema validation as shown below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [password] in table [users_aud]; found [binary (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$276/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 117 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [password] in table [users_aud]; found [binary (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 125 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [password] in table [users_aud]; found [binary (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 129 common frames omitted
```

### The DDL statements

Apparently, Hibernate expects a column type in the aud table different than the column type from the original table. I created the tables as follows (other columns left out for brevity):

```
create table users
(
    password                 binary(60)  not null,
) engine = InnoDB;

create table users_aud
(
    id                           bigint  not null,
    rev                          integer not null,
    revtype                      tinyint,
    revend                       integer,
    password                     binary(60),
    password_mod                 bit,
    primary key (id, rev)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

### The Entity in Java

The `User` entity in Java (other fields and equals/hashCode left out for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Table(name = "users")
public abstract class User extends HasId implements UserDetails {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(60)", nullable = false)
    private String password;

}
```

### The Hibernate config

My Hibernate config looks as follows (application.yml for Spring Boot):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        connection:
          provider_disables_autocommit: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
        implicit_naming_strategy: component-path
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            audit_strategy: org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy
            global_with_modified_flag: true
```

### Final notes

The strange thing is that it worked perfectly until the version upgrade. Unfortunately, I can't find anything related to this issue in the [5.4.11](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=31818&styleName=Html&projectId=10031) or [5.4.12](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=31827&styleName=Html&projectId=10031) release notes except for maybe [this one](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10844). The database is MySQL version 5.7.

Comment: Hi, this definitely sounds like it is a bug; reported as https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13922.

Comment: @Naros thank you for creating a bug report! I'm glad to hear that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Indeed, as a follow-up I applied a fix to Hibernate Envers master branch so this should be resolved in the next release, most likely 5.4.14.